# Sum file upload input tags size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have more than one input `type=file` tags in my form. Sometimes one will be hidden and sometimes there will be multiples created dynamically. I would like that on my form submit I check the file size of each file and I would sum them and check if it exceeds the maximum I set.

I wrote the code below:

```
function AcceptableFileUpload() {
    var totalsize = 0;
    var fileUploads = $("#form1 input[type=file]").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileUploads; i++) {
        //I added this to check whether there is any file here 
        //as I was receiving undefined when my hidden input file was checked
        if ($('#form1 input[type=file]').get(i).length > 0) {
            var filesize = $('#form1 input[type=file]').get(i).files[0].size;
            totalsize = +filesize;
        }
    }
    if (totalsize > 1073741) {
        alert("File size limit exceeded");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I only used `var filesize = $('#form1 input[type=file]').get(0).files[0].size;` I got the file size correctly, but it didn't work the way I wrote above, it says that the size is 0 always. I'd appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: which browser are you using ? safari browser will show size zero on multiple file upload !.

Comment: I am testing on Firefox(24.0) and Chrome (30.0.1599.69)

Comment: if possible create one fiddle with your workaround.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, my file uploads are not "multiple", I may have more than one input type="file" tags. Each one will only have one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
function AcceptableFileUpload() {
   var totalsize = 0;

   $('#form1 input:file').each(function(){
     if($(this).val().length > 0){
        totalsize=totalsize+$(this)[0].files[0].size;
      }
  });
  if (totalsize > 1073741) {
      alert("File size limit exceeded");
      return false;
  }
  return true;
```

}